# Can I use image size ultra-low on iPad? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

Can I use image size ultra-low on iPad?

I'm reading this lesson : http://lessons.runrev.com/m/15262/l/156530-how-do-i-support-different-device-screen-densities

I want to create the page with scrolling for image.
At first when stack is open, scrolling group should display ultra-low image.After scrolling group has stopped it should display ultra-high image for iPad Retina display.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a native scroller for that and use acceleratedRendering:

```
on preOpenStack
   set the acceleratedRendering to true
end preOpenStack
```

Then on your card:

```
-- Create a native scrolling group
-- Create the image in the scrolling group
set the layerMode of myScrollingGroup to "scrolling"
```

You should now be able to navigate around the image perfectly smoothly on any iOS device.

Comment: I did follow your suggestion but I feel it's not enough to smooth. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What version of LiveCode are you doing this on?

Comment: How does it perform in 6.5.2?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Have you tried running your app in LiveCode 6.5.2? In 6.6/6.7 we added high DPI support and in same cases there are performance slowdowns. This may be one of them. Try the scrolling component of your app in 6.5.2 and let me know if it's faster. If so, we can fix it in 6.7.

Comment: I download livecode version 6.5.2 stable.In preference on mobile support I can't setting iOS SDKs.I have error message "The chosen folder is not a valid iOS SDK.". How do I do?

Comment: Ah yes, you would also need an older version of xCode. If you send your stack to support@runrev.com they'll pass it one to me. Send a link to this thread in your email. If you can just send the part of your program that does the scrolling that would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried your stack on our Retina iPad air and performance is great. Please see the video I uploaded here which shows this-

http://techsupport.on-rev.com/sostacks/kemchat.zip

Could you explain in more detail the slow down you are experiencing?

I did notice that you are using a popup menu button within one section of the app. As these are not technically supported on mobile devices, I would recommend the use of the “mobilePick” syntax.